# Provisioning Datasources for multiple organizations - only first one works

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am setting up a Grafana instance that will have multiple organizations (SaaS, Dev, DevOps) and want to us provisioning files. each org will basically have the same data sources. I have tried using the same yaml file multiple times (different file name, and different orgID) and I tried having one file with multiple definitions in it but in each case the provisioning is only applied to org 1. When I go into the datasources for org 1 I can see the banner notifying me to “contact your server admin” but for org 2 and 3 they are still free form.

Some examples:

```
$ more site1.yaml
# # config file version
apiVersion: 1

# list of datasources that should be deleted from the database
deleteDatasources:

datasources:
  - &main_datasource
    name: site1-Main
    isDefault: false
    access: proxy
    type: prometheus
    org_id: 1
    url: http://<<myserver>>:9090
    editable: false
    version: 2
  - <<: *main_datasource
    org_id: 2
  - <<: *main_datasource
    org_id: 3
```

And I tried:

```
$ more site2-tsdb.yaml
# # config file version
apiVersion: 1

# list of datasources that should be deleted from the database
deleteDatasources:

datasources:
  - name: site2-TSDB
    isDefault: false
    access: proxy
    type: prometheus
    org_id: 1
    url: http://<<myserver>>:8428
    editable: false
  - name: site2-TSDB
    isDefault: false
    access: proxy
    type: prometheus
    org_id: 2
    url: http://<<myserver>>:8428
    editable: false
  - name: site2-TSDB
    isDefault: false
    access: proxy
    type: prometheus
    org_id: 3
    url: http://<<myserver>>:8428
    editable: false
```

There are no errors in the logs.

Thoughts?

Comment: It should be `orgId: <number>` and not `org_id: <number>`

Comment: Precision: since there is a typo in the org, they all defaults to org 1. That's why it works in this case. Funny thing that grafana doesn't warn about unknown parameters.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDoubez , not sure how I missed that.  Once I made the change it worked fine.  Thanks for your response....